# Is there a Javascript/Json equivalent to .NET reflection to iterate over an object's members?

Tags: jquery, json

Take this Json object for example:

> var x = $.parseJSON("[{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":\"23\"},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"age\":\"30\"}]");

(Mind all the `\"`.  I don't like using single quotes.  Go ahead and sue me.)

What I am ultimately going for is a dynamically generated HTML table that's based on the data and structure of my Json object (think of the AutoGenerateColumns property of many WebForms grids).  To create the header, I would iterate through each member and create a header column using the member name.  This way, all I need to do is add or remove columns from the SQL in my WebMethod call and the table will be updated automatically.

**Solution**

This JS does the trick:

```
        var x = $.parseJSON("[{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":\"23\"},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"age\":\"30\"}]");

        $.each(x, (function (key, value) {
            $.each(x[key], function (key2, value2) {
                alert(key2 + " " + x[key][key2]);
            });
        }));
```

I haven't done much looping through stuff in JS, so one thing that got me was the key.  In .NET, a `foreach` loop iterates through the objects in the collection.  In JS, `for` iterates through the indexes, hence why I had to go like `x[key][key2]`.

Comment: [datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) perhaps?

Comment: btw, "Mind all the `\"`"....It's your carpel tunnel, not mine. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) can do that, so can a native javascript "foreach" (aka [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in)). Both provide you the ability to iterative over the keys of an object. So, for your example:

```
var columns = []; // column holder
// grab first element (assuming they all have the same columns)
var first = x[0];
// iterative over eahc property and add it to our columns list
for (var key in first){
  columns.push(key);
}
```

Now columns would have `['name','age']`.

Comment: Great start.  I am able to dynamically build my header.  However, how about dynamically iterating over the columns to get the member values?

Comment: In that `for...in` you can reference `first[key]` and get the value. JS lets you reference objects using `object.property` or `prop = 'property'; object[prop]` (using a variable).

Comment: I finally figured it out.  See my update.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $.parseJSON("[{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":\"23\"},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"age\":\"30\"}]");

for (var prop in x) {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Something important to note there is the `hasOwnProperty` method. This method checks to see if it's a property that came directly from `x` or from whatever object `x` descends from (such as `Object`).